# Make Background Transparent w/ rounded effect - UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Using this function rounds the image, but it leaves a white background, how do I turn the background transparent?

```
func roundImage() -> UIImage
{
    let newImage = self.copy() as! UIImage
    let cornerRadius = self.size.height/2

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false , 0.0)
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.size)
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
    newImage.drawInRect(bounds)
    let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return finalImage
}
```

Comment: Well it should be transparent, is it a jpeg or a png?

Comment: Try newImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: value of type uiimage has no member backgroundColor

Comment: Value of Type UIImage has no member 'clipsToBounds'.  you're confusing uiimage with uiimageview i think.

Comment: What are you doing with the image after this?

Comment: @TimNuwin is your image transparent to begin with? Or are you just trying to replace a white background with transparency?

Comment: it is not transparent to begin with